# Автор постов

Tags: wordpress

Доброе время суток!
У меня к Вам вопрос. Требуется сделать так, чтобы авторами на блоге могли быть несколько человек, а админ-то один.

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в админ-панель, там есть пункт "Пользователи", выберите нужного пользователя, и поставте ему необходимую роль (Автор/Редактор).

Также есть специальный [плагин](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/), который дает возможность расширенного редактирования ролей.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую